# Lost a PST file on the network

Tags: networking, outlook, lost

Yesterday I migrated a user inbox to a new .pst on the network, but this morning the pst file has just disappeared. I had no error or warning during moving the files from the inbox to the external pst in Outlook and I saw the pst file growing on the Network (700MB), but when this person tried to log on this morning Outlook couldn't find the pst file, and there's a good reason for that: the PST file is just not here anymore.
I tried restoring the OST saved locally to PST but it was too late and only the sent items are in it (as I did not move them to the new PSt file).

Do you know any way of restoring the PST file or retrieving the emails? I feel like there's no solution...

Nicolas.

Comment: Restore from backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my issue actually! After spending almost an hour trying to find a way to recover the file, I noticed that the file was actually there. As we have a specific folder structure I used one of the other pst already in the folder as a "template" to create the new one, so once I've copied it it was called "*something* - Copy.pst" which I renamed to *newuser*.pst before openning it in Outlook and moving all the files.

Without ANY reason, this morning the file *newuser*.pst was named "*something* - Copy.pst", which led the file *newuser*.pst not to be open in Outlook. The fix was then just to rename -again- the "*something* - Copy.pst" to *newuser*.pst

I have no idea how this happened, but now the user has all his emails back!

Nicolas.

Comment: you can mark this as the solution by clicking the tick next to this answer. Marking this as the solution shows anyone else on the internet who finds this question that this solved your problem.

Comment: @Ben: Actually I tried and I can't. I need to wait for 2 days before doing so...

Answer (score 1):

Restore from your most recent backup. I don't think there is any other solution.